# How to monitor ProvisionedThroughputExceededException in AWS kinesis stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

From the Kinesis Stream side, is there a way to display how many times or how many records were thrown away because of `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException`, the quota that allows no more than 1000 records or 6 mb of data to be written per second to a shard?

Comment: There's a CloudWatch metric that can be used to monitor this. More important, a well-behaved client _does not throw away records_ due to throughput exceeded. instead, your clients should retry the entire request for `PutRecord`, or the failed records for `PutRecords`.

Comment: You would need to enable enhanced monitoring for the stream and then the metric could be plotted in cloud watch dashboard. Generally if you have heavy load the client would need to do the exponential retry incase you dont want to miss the data.